# Cross compiled binary apparently needs more shared libraries than a natively compiled one

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, cross-platform

I am working on a cross compilation setup with the host being x86_64 (Ubuntu 16.04) and the target being NVidia's Jetson Nano (aarch64, Ubuntu 18.04). The target has the capability of native compilation. I observe that the cross compiled binary needs more shared libraries to be linked to during run-time, than a natively compiled binary on the Jetson Nano does. Of course, the source code is exactly the same and I use a CMake-based build configuration. To check the needed shared libraries for the so-generated binary to execute, I run the command:
`readelf -d <binary> | grep 'NEEDED'`

To do cross compilation, I use the below toolchain file:

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 4.9.140)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR aarch64)
SET(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING 1)
SET(CUDA_TOOLKIT_INCLUDE "/usr/local/cuda/include") # for Could NOT find CUDA (missing: CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS) with cmake v 3.8 or higher (tested with 3.10)
SET(CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR "/usr/local/cuda")
SET(CUDA_VERSION "10.0") # This is like tricking the build system, otherwise FindCUDA.cmake on host tries to run an aarch64 binary
SET(CUDA_USE_STATIC_CUDA_RUNTIME OFF CACHE INTERNAL "")

SET(ROOTFS "$ENV{CROSS_ROOT}" CACHE INTERNAL "Copied from environment variable")
SET(TXROOT "${ROOTFS}")
SET(CC_PACKAGE_DIR "$ENV{BASE_DIR}" CACHE INTERNAL "Copied from environment variable")
SET(TOOLROOT "${CC_PACKAGE_DIR}/Toolchain/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu")


include_directories(${TXROOT}/usr/local/cuda/include)
include_directories(${TXROOT}/usr/local/cuda/samples/common/inc)


SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${TOOLROOT}/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${TOOLROOT}/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++)

SET(CMAKE_LINKER "${TOOLROOT}/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld" CACHE FILEPATH "" FORCE)
SET(CMAKE_AR "${TOOLROOT}/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ar" CACHE FILEPATH "" FORCE)

SET(FLAGS "-Wl,-rpath-link,${TXROOT}/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -Wl,-rpath-link,${TXROOT}/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu")
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS ${FLAGS} CACHE STRING "" FORCE)

SET(CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY "${TXROOT}/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudart.so") # Only neeeded from Cmake v 3.8 and higher

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-L${TXROOT}/usr/local/cuda/lib64")
SET(CMAKE_SYSROOT "${TXROOT}")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} --sysroot=${TXROOT}" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
SET(CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_LINK_FLAGS} --sysroot=${TXROOT}" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} --sysroot=${TXROOT}" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS} --sysroot=${TXROOT}" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)

SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH "${TXROOT}")
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
SET(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```

And before running the cross compilation, I set the environment using the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

whereami() {
currdir="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" > /dev/null && pwd -L)"
echo "$currdir"
}

BASE_DIR=$(whereami)

extract_rootfs() {
if [ ! -d "$BASE_DIR/rootfs" ]; then
    echo "Extracting rootfs for cross compilation, you need to have sudo rights for this"
    sudo tar -xvjSf $BASE_DIR/rootfs.tar.bz2 -C $BASE_DIR/
fi
}


extract_rootfs
export LC_ALL=C
export BASE_DIR=$BASE_DIR
export CROSS_ROOT=$BASE_DIR/rootfs
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$CROSS_ROOT/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu:$CROSS_ROOT/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu:$CROSS_ROOT/usr/lib:$CROSS_ROOT/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export OpenCV_DIR=$BASE_DIR/rootfs/home/ubuntu/opencv-install-static
export HOME=/home/ubuntu
```

The environment $HOME is changed because the CMake file uses this to determine some paths which are relevant when running the binary on the Nano (but this is all that is needed here I think).

CMake 3.10.0 is the only one (or one of the few maybe, I couldn't explore many) I found working for cross compilation, as a lower version cannot find the Boost libraries (1.65) I am using and a higher version tries to test the (cross) compiler by trying to run a test program, which fails. The Nano uses CMake 3.10.2 natively, but I am not sure if this is the issue. And gcc version is 7.5.0 in both cases.

For the cross-compilation case, since I am directly using some shared libraries compiled on the target, which in turn depend on some libraries at a specific path (/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu), I had to manually keep these libraires (aarch64) on host (x86_64) at /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu (not a good approach, but this is due to the limitation as I cannot easily get the source code of those dependencies to compile+install them again). I also had to create this link: `/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 -> /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so` on host, otherwise the *make* compained that /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 was not found.

***Now the issue:*** The cross compiled binary cannot run on the Jetson Nano, because it cannot find some shared libraries (as mentioned in the beginning about the difference in the *needed* libraries in both cases). Now I can install the missing shared libraries on the Nano (tried it, it works), but these might have some license restrictions I am afraid of, and I would not want to go down that path. The natively compiled binary runs, of course, on the Nano.

***Question:*** Any pointers as to how to debug this? I basically need to make the cross compiled binary need the exact same shared libraries to run as the natively compiled one.

Comment: can you share the output,

Comment: I get for instance the following error when I tried to run the binary: `<binary>: error while loading shared libraries: libnppicc.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. This is one of the libraries which is listed under the _needed_ libraries for the cross compiled binary but not for the natively compiled one. If I provide this library in the standard path, I get errors for subsequent 'missing' libraries on by one. Actually this is a cuda library - not used directly by the application I am working on but via an opencv dependency.